# Как реализовать сохранение игры на Visual C#

Tags: c#, сериализация

В общем сабж, есть одна игра(курсовая), нужно сделать так чтобы процесс игры можно было сохранять, и загружать соответственно, читал про сериализацию, но никак не смог осуществить ее на своем проекте. Как это сделать на примере какого-нибудь объекта, т.е где и че нужно дописать/переписать в проекте, чтобы можно было бы реализовать сохранение/загрузка.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;


namespace BoxGame
{
    public enum MoveScore
    {
        NotAllowed = -1,
        Zero = 0,
        One = 1,
        Two = 2
    }

    public enum BoxDirection
    {
        Up,
        Down,
        Left,
        Right
    }

    class GameBoard : IGameBoard, ICornerMapper
    {
        List<List<Corner>> m_CornerRows;
        List<IMove> m_Moves;
        List<Move> m_RemainingMoves;
        List<Box> m_Boxes;
        IGraphicProvider m_Graphics;

        readonly int m_Rows;
        readonly int m_Columns;
        readonly int m_PointsPerInch = 2;
        readonly int m_PossibleLines;

        public GameBoard(int rows, int columns)
        {
            m_Rows = rows;
            m_Columns = columns;

            m_CornerRows = new List<List<Corner>>(m_Rows);
            for (int i = 0; i < m_Rows; i++)
            {
                List<Corner> row = new List<Corner>(m_Columns);
                for (int col = 0; col < m_Columns; col++)
                {
                    row.Add(new Corner(new Point(col, i), this, Color.Black));
                }
                m_CornerRows.Add(row);
            }

            m_PossibleLines = ((m_Rows - 1) * m_Columns) + ((m_Columns - 1) * m_Rows);
            m_Moves = new List<IMove>(m_PossibleLines);
            PopulateAvailableMoves();

            m_Boxes = new List<Box>( (m_Rows-1) * (m_Columns-1) );
        }

        public int MovesRemaining
        {
            get
            {
                return m_PossibleLines - m_Moves.Count;
            }
        }

        public List<Move> AvailableMoves
        {
            get
            {
                return m_RemainingMoves;
            }
        }

        public MoveScore MakeMove(IMove move, Player p)
        {
            List<Box> results  = SpeculateMove(move, p);
            bool foundSlot = false;
            foreach(Move m in AvailableMoves)
            {
                if (move.CompareTo(m) == 0)
                {
                    m.SetPlayer(p);
                    AvailableMoves.Remove(m);
                    Moves.Add(m);
                    foundSlot = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(foundSlot);

            MoveScore score = MoveScore.Zero;
            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Box b in results)
                {
                    m_Boxes.Add(b);
                    score = BumpScore(score);
                }

                p.AddScore(results.Count);
            }

            return score;
        }

        void PopulateAvailableMoves()
        {
            m_RemainingMoves = new List<Move>(m_PossibleLines);
            for (int row = 0; row < m_Rows; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < m_Columns; col++)
                {
                    if (col != m_Columns - 1)
                    {
                        Line l = new Line(m_CornerRows[row][col], m_CornerRows[row][col + 1]);
                        Move m = new Move(l);
                        if (IsAvailableMove(m))
                        {
                            m_RemainingMoves.Add(m);
                        }
                    }

                    if (row != m_Rows - 1)
                    {
                        Line l = new Line(m_CornerRows[row][col], m_CornerRows[row + 1][col]);
                        Move m = new Move(l);
                        if (IsAvailableMove(m))
                        {
                            m_RemainingMoves.Add(m);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public IGraphicProvider GraphicsProvider
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Graphics;
            }
            set
            {
                m_Graphics = value;
            }
        }

        int IGameBoard.Rows
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Rows;
            }
        }

        int IGameBoard.Columns
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Columns;
            }
        }

        ICorner[] IGameBoard.this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return m_CornerRows[index].ToArray();
            }
        }



        bool bgRendered = false;
        public void Render(IGraphicProvider gfx)
        {
            if (bgRendered == false)
            {
                Bitmap b = GenerateEmptyBackground(Color.White);
                gfx.DrawImage(b, 0, 0);
                bgRendered = true;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < m_Rows; i++)
            {
                List<Corner> row = m_CornerRows[i];
                foreach (Corner c in row)
                {
                    c.Render(gfx);
                }
            }

            foreach (IMove m in m_Moves)
            {
                m.Render(gfx);
            }

            foreach (Box b in m_Boxes)
            {
                b.Render(gfx);
            }

            gfx.Invalidate();
        }


        public Point GetGraphicsPoint(ICorner corner)
        {
            int SpacingX = m_Graphics.DpiX / m_PointsPerInch;
            int SpacingY = m_Graphics.DpiY / m_PointsPerInch;

            for (int row = 0; row < m_Rows; row++)
            {
                for (int index = 0; index < m_Columns; index++)
                {
                    if(corner.Equals(m_CornerRows[row][index]))
                    {
                        int x = (SpacingX * index + SpacingX);
                        int y = (SpacingY * row + SpacingY);
                        return new Point(x, y);
                    }
                }
            }

            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("corner");
        }

        public Size GetMinimumGraphicsSize(int DpiX, int DpiY)
        {
            int SpacingX = DpiX / m_PointsPerInch;
            int SpacingY = DpiY / m_PointsPerInch;
            int width = m_Columns * SpacingX + SpacingX;
            int height = m_Rows * SpacingY + SpacingY;

            return new Size(width, height);
        }

        static int Distance(Point p1, Point p2)
        {
            double xprime = Math.Pow((p1.X - p2.X), 2);
            double yprime = Math.Pow((p1.Y - p2.Y), 2);
            return (int) Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(xprime + yprime));
        }

        public ICorner ClosestCornerFromGraphicsPoint(Point p)
        {
            ICorner nearest = null;
            int dist = int.MaxValue;

            for (int row = 0; row < m_Rows; row++)
            {
                foreach (ICorner c in m_CornerRows[row])
                {
                    int temp = Distance(p, this.GetGraphicsPoint(c));
                    if (temp < dist)
                    {
                        dist = temp;
                        nearest = c;
                    }
                }
            }

            return nearest;
        }


        private static void SetBGColor(Bitmap b, Color c)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < b.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < b.Height; y++)
                {
                    b.SetPixel(x, y, c);
                }
            }
        }

        private Bitmap GenerateEmptyBackground(Color bgColor)
        {
            Size s = GetMinimumGraphicsSize(m_Graphics.DpiX, m_Graphics.DpiY);
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, m_Graphics.PixelFormat);
            SetBGColor(b, bgColor);

            return b;
        }


        private bool CornerPointOnBoard(Point p)
        {
            return (p.X >= 0 && p.X < m_Columns &&
                    p.Y >= 0 && p.Y < m_Rows);
        }

        public List<IMove> Moves
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Moves;
            }
        }

        public bool AreBoxableCorners(Corner ul, Corner ur, Corner ll, Corner lr)
        {
            bool areBoxable = false;
            if (CornerPointOnBoard(ul.Location) && CornerPointOnBoard(ur.Location) &&
                CornerPointOnBoard(ll.Location) && CornerPointOnBoard(lr.Location))
            {
                if (ul.IsAdjacentTo(ll) && ul.IsAdjacentTo(ur))
                {
                    if (lr.IsAdjacentTo(ll) && lr.IsAdjacentTo(ur))
                    {
                        areBoxable = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return areBoxable;
        }

        public bool MakesBox(Corner ul, Corner ur, Corner ll, Corner lr, Move move)
        {
            int filledLines = 0;
            bool fillsGap = false;
            bool makesBox = false;

            if(AreBoxableCorners(ul, ur, ll, lr))
            {
                if (!IsAvailableMove(ul, ur))
                {
                    filledLines++;
                }
                else
                {
                    fillsGap = (move.Line.Start.Location == ul.Location &&
                                move.Line.End.Location == ur.Location);
                }

                if (!IsAvailableMove(ur, lr))
                {
                    filledLines++;
                }
                else
                {
                    fillsGap = (move.Line.Start.Location == ur.Location &&
                                move.Line.End.Location == lr.Location);
                }

                if (!IsAvailableMove(ll, lr))
                {
                    filledLines++;
                }
                else
                {
                    fillsGap = (move.Line.Start.Location == ll.Location &&
                                move.Line.End.Location == lr.Location);
                }

                if (!IsAvailableMove(ul, ll))
                {
                    filledLines++;
                }
                else
                {
                    fillsGap = (move.Line.Start.Location == ul.Location &&
                                move.Line.End.Location == ll.Location);
                }

                makesBox = filledLines == 3 && fillsGap;
            }

            return makesBox;
        }

        Corner GetCornerFromDirection(Corner orig, BoxDirection direction)
        {
            Corner result = null;

            Point newP = orig.Location;
            switch (direction)
            {
                case BoxDirection.Up:
                    newP.Offset(0, -1);
                    break;
                case BoxDirection.Down:
                    newP.Offset(0, 1);
                    break;
                case BoxDirection.Left:
                    newP.Offset(-1, 0);
                    break;
                case BoxDirection.Right:
                    newP.Offset(1, 0);
                    break;
            }

            if (CornerPointOnBoard(newP))
            {
                result = m_CornerRows[newP.Y][newP.X];
            }

            return result;
        }

        Box CreateBox(IMove move, BoxDirection direction, Player player)
        {
            bool wouldBox = false;
            Corner ul = null, ur = null, ll = null, lr = null;

            switch (direction)
            {
                case BoxDirection.Up:
                    {
                        if(!(move.Line as Line).Vertical)
                        {
                            ll = move.Line.Start as Corner;
                            ul = GetCornerFromDirection(ll, BoxDirection.Up);
                            lr = move.Line.End as Corner;
                            ur = GetCornerFromDirection(lr, BoxDirection.Up);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case BoxDirection.Down:
                    {
                        if (!(move.Line as Line).Vertical)
                        {
                            ul = move.Line.Start as Corner;
                            ur = move.Line.End as Corner;
                            ll = GetCornerFromDirection(ul, BoxDirection.Down);
                            lr = GetCornerFromDirection(ur, BoxDirection.Down);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case BoxDirection.Left:
                    {
                        if ((move.Line as Line).Vertical)
                        {
                            ur = move.Line.Start as Corner;
                            lr = move.Line.End as Corner;
                            ul = GetCornerFromDirection(ur, BoxDirection.Left);
                            ll = GetCornerFromDirection(lr, BoxDirection.Left);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case BoxDirection.Right:
                    {
                        if ((move.Line as Line).Vertical)
                        {
                            ul = move.Line.Start as Corner;
                            ll = move.Line.End as Corner;
                            ur = GetCornerFromDirection(ul, BoxDirection.Right);
                            lr = GetCornerFromDirection(ll, BoxDirection.Right);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("JILZZ");
            }

            Box box = null;

            if (ul != null && ur != null && ll != null && lr != null)
            {
                wouldBox = MakesBox(ul, ur, ll, lr, move as Move);
                if (wouldBox)
                {
                    box = new Box(ul, ur, lr, ll, player, this);
                }
            }

            return box;
        }

        static MoveScore BumpScore(MoveScore score)
        {
            switch (score)
            {
                case MoveScore.NotAllowed:
                    return MoveScore.One;
                case MoveScore.Zero:
                    return MoveScore.One;
                case MoveScore.One:
                    return MoveScore.Two;
                default:
                    return MoveScore.NotAllowed;
            }
        }

        static void AddIfNotNull(List<Box> list, Box b)
        {
            if (b != null)
            {
                list.Add(b);
            }
        }

        public List<Box> SpeculateMove(IMove move, Player player)
        {
            List<Box> results = new List<Box>();

            if (IsAvailableMove(move))
            {
                AddIfNotNull(results, CreateBox(move, BoxDirection.Up, player));
                AddIfNotNull(results, CreateBox(move, BoxDirection.Down, player));
                AddIfNotNull(results, CreateBox(move, BoxDirection.Left, player));
                AddIfNotNull(results, CreateBox(move, BoxDirection.Right, player));
            }

            return results;
        }

        public bool IsAvailableMove(Corner start, Corner end)
        {
            return IsAvailableMove(new Move(new Line(start, end)));
        }

        public bool IsAvailableMove(IMove move)
        {
            Point start = move.Line.Start.Location;
            Point end = move.Line.End.Location;

            if (CornerPointOnBoard(start) && CornerPointOnBoard(end))
            {
                foreach (Move m in m_Moves)
                {
                    if (m.Line.Start == move.Line.Start &&
                        m.Line.End == move.Line.End)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы читали официальное руководство? [Бинарная сериализация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et91as27.aspx), [XML-сериализация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szzyf24s%28v=vs.110%29).

Comment: да, прочел уже, не нравятся мне их примеры, слишком сухо

Comment: Суть сериализации в том и заключается, что сохранение и загрузка осуществляются парой строк кода. Никакой воды.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по комментариям:

> Да я прочел их инструкции, но это не то, что мне нужно, ибо в моем
>   проекте все посложнее. Не могли бы вы на примере моего кода показать,
>   как мне это реализовать?

у вас проблема не в том, как сохранить, а в том, что сохранять. В любой игре можно выделить модель, которая описывает текущее состояние игры. Для шахмат, например, это расположение фигур на доске и чей ход следующий, белых или черных. Для какого-нибудь FPS - локация, расположение игрока и врагов, уровни здоровья, активные бонусы и т.п. При этом не важно, пошаговая это игра с явно выделенными ходами игроков (самый простой случай) или игра в реальном времени с возможностью одновременных действий (чуть сложнее но суть та же), главное, что в любой момент времени, состояние игры, да и любого процесса в принципе, может быть описано определенным набором данных, и только данных. Каким образом записывать и загружать эти данные не важно. Можно последовательно записывать ходы на листочек (в текстовый файл), как партию в шахматах или собрать все данные в сериализуемый объект и вызвать соответствующий метод.

Итого вам нужно:

1. определить что именно характеризует каждый момент вашей игры.
2. Выделить в отдельную сущность модель этого состояния.
3. Реализовать сохранение и загрузку этой сущности, одним из уже предложенных вам способов.

Возможно это потребует значительных изменений в вашем коде, т.к. на собственном опыте не раз убеждался, что не возможно предусмотреть все сразу, даже строго следуя всем рекомендациям и лучшим практикам. Поэтому лучшим вариантом будет не цепляться мертвой хваткой за уже написанный код, а внимательно посмотреть на модель игры и понять что в ней не так и как ее изменить, чтобы очередная фича или пожелание преподавателя не вылилось в очередную головную боль. Вы потратите на это несколько меньше времени, чем на попытки воткнуть очередной костыль не поломав все вставленные ранее.

Answer (score 2):

Первым делом класс-модель надо пометить аннотацией `[Serializable]`

```
[Serializable]
public class Test
{
}
```

И потом самое простое это бинарное сохранение

```
Test test = new Test();
FileStream fs = File.Create("test.dat");
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(fs, test);
fs.Close();
```

И чтение

```
fs = File.OpenRead("test.dat");
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
Test testFile = (Test)bf.Deserialize(fs);
fs.Close();
```

Подробнее про форматы записи (бинарный, SOAP) с пошаговыми инструкциями можно почитать тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/et91as27.aspx

Comment: Да я прочел их инструкции, но это не то, что мне нужно, ибо в моем проекте все посложнее. Не могли бы вы на примере моего кода показать, как мне это реализовать?

Comment: @DarthGandalf, так вы покажите свой код.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov добавил объект из проекта, данные из которого нужно сохранять/выгружать .